# Computer “freezes” and Internet “issue”, that only gets fixed with ctrl+alt+del

Tags: windows, windows-10, internet, freeze, ctrl-alt-delete

So my problem with my pc and internet (not sure though) came up a few days ago. The thing is when I do anything on my computer, for example let's take browsing on Opera.

I'm browsing on a site like Reddit and then I open a new tab and try to go to Youtube.

I press the Youtube from like this quick tool thingy and Youtube won't open and the internet just loads, as if I had no connection.

As this happens I can try anything related to the internet, like Discord or Spotify, it won't load. Also happens with apps, that don't use internet.

As this happens I can't even open my Task Manager from my taskbar and the only fix is pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>, but when I do so it takes like a minute to go to the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> screen and then when I come back everything functions normally, like always.

When I don't have the issue I can just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> and it goes to that screen in 1sec, so I don't know why this happens.

Do you have any clues on what could be the cause for this problem?

Comment: Possible hard disk failure. Check your hard drives for SMART errors [How can I read my hard drive’s SMART status in Windows 7?](//superuser.com/q/29240), and [What is the easiest method of checking SMART status for your hard drive?](//superuser.com/q/14803). Report back with the results.

Comment: @DavidPostill thanks for the answer, will do, but can't today. I have to do some stuff today, so I won't be near my pc. Is it ok, if I post it tomorrow?

Comment: @BenjaminHirschbok take your time pal, when you have some results edit your question to address those.

Comment: I'm gonna be honest with you, this SMART error checking app is beyond my knowledge of PCs and I can't get further, than the installation. No actually to be honest, after I installing it there is an install text file to be found and I can't quite understand how the installation works. For now I'm stuck. @DavidPostill

Answer (score 0):

There may be some reasons that you can try to fix in order to fix the freezing of your system. I'm illustrating a few of them.

1. Hardware incompatibility
2. Issues with Windows registry
3. Malware issues.
4. Antivirus problem.
5. Driver issues.
6. User tweaks.
7. Bugs in the application.

You can check out to fix these issues to eliminate the issues with your system.